# clojurescript advanced compilation - size

Tags: clojurescript

I am new to clojurescript.

Is it normal to have a javascript file of "77 KB" after advanced compilation?

I have one clojurescript file:

I am using leinigen: lein cljsbuild once

```
(ns my-staff.core)
 (defn ^:export main []
   (.write js/document "<p>Hello from my_staff.core.main()</p>")) 

(defproject my-staff "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-1586"]]
  :source-paths ["src-clj"]; source path for clojure
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "0.3.0"]]
  :cljsbuild {
     :builds [{
          :source-paths ["src-cljs"]
          :compiler {
          :output-to "public/javascripts/main.js"
          :optimizations :advanced
          :pretty-print false}}]})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's normal. The Google Closure compiler has trouble optimizing some of the code that the clojurescript compiler currently emits. This is expected to improve over time. Check [CLJS-257](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-257) for progress.